# C writing to string (specific function asked)

Tags: c, string, int

I am kind of in a pinch with searching one specific function with return type int which changes the values of a char array (string) by taking exactly 5 parametres whereas the function must not be imported from any other library with an exception of `stdio.h` maybe.

The source looks like in following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char buffer [50];
  int n;

  n= // some function here ;

  printf("%s",buffer,n);
  return 0; 
}
```

I have been looking into many functions, but none I knew of or found match the above requirement such that I'd appreciate the help of more knowledgeable people now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework or a quiz or something? Asking because it's a strange question.

Comment: Thats strange. Why are 5 parameters a requirement?

Comment: Why extra argument in `printf`? What is the expected output? You are possibly looking for [`fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) which takes 4 parameters.

Comment: `sprintf` could possibly take 5 arguments ...

Comment: Are you looking for `snprintf()` or one of its relatives?

Comment: Its look weired question , but still I want to clarify most of the string related functions are stored in the string.h header file and its not matching to your condition to take stdio.h , can you plz elaborate what task you want to do .

Comment: It's a meaningless requirement. Please quote your assignment verbatim. `printf("%s",buffer,n);` doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Probably just `n = scanf("%s %s %s %s", buffer, buffer, buffer, buffer)`? The question is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go with functions with variable argument lists. 
Two such ones in `stdio.h` are:

```
int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

Note: These functions do not exactly take five arguments as you specified in your question. They take a minimum number of arguments (2 & 3 respectively) but can go way beyond 5 arguments.

> which changes the values of a char array (string)

The following does what you want to char array (`info`):

```
char info[60];
char name[] = "Christopher Westburry";
char designation[] = "Learner"; 
int reputation = 72;
sprintf(info, "Welcome %s to StackOverflow!\nDesignation: %s\nReputation: %d",
    name, designation, reputation);
printf("%s", info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Skimming [Appendix B of the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf#page=430&zoom=auto,-18,792), I don't see anything that takes ***exactly*** 5 arguments and returns an `int`.

OTOH `stdio.h` is full of functions that return an `int` and take a *variable* number of arguments in the `scanf` and `printf` family. Once can contrive something. Since `buffer` is uninitialized, and the code wants to print it, presumably we're going to read something into it from `stdin`. That probably means some contrived `scanf` call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char buffer [50];
  int n;

  // Same as
  // n = scanf("%40s", buffer);
  n = scanf(
      "%10s%10s%10s%10s",
      buffer,
      &buffer[10],
      &buffer[20],
      &buffer[30]
  );

  // printf("%s",buffer,n);
  printf("'%s' %d\n",buffer,n);
  return 0; 
}
```

If that's the answer they expect, this exercise is pretty pointless.

Note that the `printf` in the original code has a bug where it's passed in too many arguments. Maybe that's a clue and this is supposed to be some clever use of [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)?